# Count frequency of two words occuring together in a sentence

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, token, spacy

I have a pandas dataframe where in one column I have the lemmatised text.

I would like to compute the frequency of two given words appearing together in the same sentence and compute how many times in the document those words appeared together. For example given "I" and "have", compute how many times in a document "I" and "have" appeared together in the same sentence.

Ideally, I would like to create a new DataFrame with the results where in one column I have the two words together and in the other the count of the two words appearing together in one sentence and in the third column the original text.

My results would need to be something like :

```
text, given_words, frequency_in_sentence
text1 | "I have " | 2 times in same sentence 
text2 | "I have " | 3 times in same sentence 
text3 | "I have " | 1 times in same sentence
```

Comment: Please check out [Minimal Reproducible Example] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it will help you phrase the question in a way that will make it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pseudo code but can be adopted to any language:

```
word1="whatever"
word2="yes"


for (text:texts)
     sentances=text.getSentances()

count=0
for (sentance:sentances)
     if ( sentance.contains(word1,word2) )
          count++

print ( "text " + text.name + " " + word1 + " " + word2 + " appears in same sentances " + count + " times" )
```

Then you would need method like below for "sentance"

```
boolean contains (String ... words){
     int args = words.length;     
     int matchCount=0;
     for (word : words)
           if (this.text.match(word)
                 matchCount++ && continue


     if matchCount==args
           return true


     return false
}
```

Comment: for reads like a "for each" and assuming you can create objects or some kind of entity to represent the concepts you are trying to work with. The ... means "variable arguments" meaning they are passed to a function as an array of strings , there can be 0 to whatever the max number of items can be stored in array

Comment: how would you do it in Python?

Comment: Are you asking me how to run a python script or solve a problem??? Assuming you can run a simple hello world in python, just change syntax to py and put it in a file myprog.py and run it via `python` from command line? Or however you have it setup. Keep in mind this is PSEUDO code , so you will need to modify it to get it to work

Comment: This is an analysis of collocation, you can do this without any effort using nltk.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `count` and use it via an apply function on your dataframe:

```
def count(sentence, pattern):
    """ count pattern occurence """
    return word.count(sentence)

df['frequency_in_sentence'] = df.apply(lambda row:count(row['text'], row['given_words']), axis = 1)
```